# How to check current strings in MYSQL_HISTIGNORE?

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, database, mysql-5.6

In mysql 5.6 a new parameter histignore is introduced to avoid writing of history file for some particular keywords.

I run the mysql shell by setting two string in histignore parameter as:

```
./bin/mysql --histignore="*UPDATE*:*DELETE*"
```

I want to know how to check this variable current values ?

Whats the command to check present values of this variable ?

Comment: Documentation says it's **MySQL** environment variable. You use MySQL shell and issue something like `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%hist%'` - adjust the wildcard as you see fit.

Comment: I tried this, but it returns nothing..

Comment: Ha, turns out I didn't read the manual properly so my previous comment is absolutely wrong. The MySQL env. variables are set in the OS and then MySQL uses them. Try using `printenv MYSQL_HISTIGNORE` to check its value, if it's set. Also, why downvotes, the question seems valid to me, it's obvious how the docs can be a bit misleading..

Comment: Thanks @N.B.
I got the solution

Comment: Alright, glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution:

We need to set the variable as:

```
export MYSQL_HISTIGNORE="*INSERT*"
```

and we can check via command :

```
printenv MYSQL_HISTIGNORE
```